# Need to display single post of a user on each page Neo4j Cypher

Tags: neo4j, subquery, cypher

I want to display a single post of each user on each page in descending order by CreatedDateTime. 
For example:
If John has created three posts

Post A at 09:00 31-Jan

Post B at 10:00 31-Jan

Post C at 11:00 31 Jan

So the required output shoud be

Page 1 should display Post C

Page 2 should display Post B

Page 3 should display Post A

This means there will be 20 posts for 20 different users on a single page.

So far I wrote this query which displays all the posts on page one.

```
 MATCH (p:Posts)-[:CREATED_BY]->(u:User)
 WHERE p.CreatedDateTime >= datetime('2021-01-31')
 RETURN p, u
 ORDER BY datetime(p.CreatedDateTime) DESC
 SKIP 0
 LIMIT 20
```

I know, need to use some subquery but don't have clue how to do that.

TYIA

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
 MATCH (p:Posts)-[:CREATED_BY]->(u:User)
 WHERE p.CreatedDateTime >= datetime('2021-01-31') 
 WITH p, u
 ORDER BY datetime(p.CreatedDateTime) DESC
 WITH u, collect(p)[$page] as post
 WHERE NOT post is null
 RETURN u, post
```

that gives you for always incrementing page numbers always the latest post
With apoc you could use instead apoc.agg.nth(p, $page)

Comment: This seems working but when I put SKIP, LIMIT. it put limit on number of users but not on the post. 
Lets say we have 2 posts created by 1000 users.
and on one page I put limit to show 10 users posts. So this means
On 1st page it will show 1st post of each user. 
Then on 2nd it will show 2nd post of next 10 users. but on 3rd page it shows no data. How to handle this? Please help. Thanks